# How To Sort Wordpress Repeated Field

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Can Somebody Please Help me Out in sorting of wordpress repeated fields.

I have repeated fields that contains value like this -

1st - 100GB,1 Month,Unlimited,$300
2nd - 200GB,1 Month,Unlimited,$500
3rd - 10GB,1 Month,Unlimited,$100

Above are the examples of my repeating fields .
I want to display those in accending order..
like this -

3rd - 10GB,1 Month,Unlimited,$100
1st - 100GB,1 Month,Unlimited,$300
2nd - 200GB,1 Month,Unlimited,$500

Actually I want to get it sorted by using price..so the array with lowest price comes first.

Here is my code :-

```
<?php $every =  get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'wpcf-plan-feature', false ); foreach($every as $every1) { ?>
<?php $feat = explode(',', $every1); {?>

<ul class="liststyle5">
<li class="ram"><?php echo $feat[0]; ?></li>
<li class="storage"><?php echo $feat[1]; ?></li>
<li class="bw"><?php echo $feat[2]; ?></li>
<li class="orange"><?php echo $feat[3]; ?></li>
</ul>   <?php }}
                 ?>
```

I am using types plugin for custom fields.

Comment: Is [**this**](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/is-it-possible-to-display-the-get_post_meta-array-in-order) what you want?

Comment: are you storing the dollar sign in the prices?

Comment: i am not storing $ sign in the prices..its just Numeric pattern .

Answer (score 1):

You should look into Advanced Custom Fields. I'm not one for using a lot of plugins but this one is legit.  ACF will help with repeaters, sorting and grabbing content. Here's a little an example on how to sort the repeater fields http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to/how-to-sorting-a-repeater-field/

ACF saves a bunch of time and is worth a look.